# Java If statement fails go back and ask to try again

Tags: java, loops

```
Scanner scannerObject= new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter what maths to use:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for Division");
    n1=scannerObject.nextInt();

    if(n1>4) {
        System.out.println("That is not an option. Please try again");
```

i want to have if n1>4 it will ask again

Comment: So, you probably want same kind of loop - maybe start with [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)

Comment: If statement should control sequence not iteration.  For do should control iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap inside the loop, and use else to break

```
while(true){
Scanner scannerObject= new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter what maths to use:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for Division");
    n1=scannerObject.nextInt();

    if(n1>4) {
        System.out.println("That is not an option. Please try again");
}
   else break; //this will make exit the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you probably want same kind of loop - maybe start with [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)

Maybe something like...

```
int n1 = -1;
do {
    Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter what maths to use:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for Division");
    n1 = scannerObject.nextInt();

    if (n1 > 4) {
        System.out.println("That is not an option. Please try again");
    }
} while (n1 < 1 && n1 > 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple boolean condition.

```
boolean conditionNotMet = true;
while(conditionNotMet){
Scanner scannerObject= new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter what maths to use:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for Division");
    n1=scannerObject.nextInt();

    conditionNotMet = false;
    if(n1>4) {
        conditionNotMet = true;
        System.out.println("That is not an option. Please try again");
     }
}
//continue processing using valid n1...
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to have a way to get back to the question list after the if statement. The best way would be to put all of your questions in a loop.

```
Scanner scannerObject= new Scanner(System.in) ;
boolean answered = false;
while(!answered)
{
    System.out.println("Enter what maths to use:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for Division");
    n1=scannerObject.nextInt();

    if(n1>4) 
    {
        System.out.println("That is not an option. Please try again");
    }
    else 
    {
        answered = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can try breaking your codes into logical methods.
which helps to make your code more readable.

```
boolean isValidInput;
int input =-1;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
    printMenu();
    input = getInt(scanner); //this will check that the input is an int

    if(input >0 && input<=4) { isValidInput = true;}
    else { System.out.println("selection invalid. Try again.");

}while (!isValidInput); //keeps looping until a valid input is entered.

switch(input){
   case 1: ... your code logic here...

}
```

below will be how you write your utility methods

```
static void printMenu(){
    System.out.println("Enter what maths to use:");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for addition");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Subtraction");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for multiplication");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 for Division");
}
```

remember to do error checks to prevent app from crashing if user enter a string instead.

```
static int getInt(Scanner scanner){
    int result =0;
    while(true){ //loop forever
    try{
       result=scanner.nextInt();
       return result; //it will return if there's no error
    }catch (Exception e){
       scanner.nextLine(); //clear the scanner
       System.out.println("not an integer! try again: ");
    }
    }
}
```